# Find Regex for email with specific words at its end

Tags: java, regex

I know its an old question but I was unable to solve a question and I wanted to get a solution.

I was asked to validate a regex of email such that the letters before `@` consists of a-z, A-Z , 0-9 , `.` and `_`. After domain i.e `@` , it should have a-z or `-` . The last value followed can be only among `com`, `net` or `org`.

I tried to partially solve it  with regex :

> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9.]+@[a-z-]+\\.com$")

which didn't work. What I found was that even

> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9.]+@[a-z-]+")

wasn't working even for ids like : `test@domain.xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be how you are finding the matches. Like @GalAbra mentioned, you are missing some parts of the regex.

See java code below:

```
Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z\\._]+@[a-z\\-]+\\.(com|net|org)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher mMatcher = mPattern.matcher("test@domain.org\ntest@do-main.com\nfoo@bar.net");
while(mMatcher.find()){
    System.out.println(mMatcher.group());
}
```

Returns:

```
test@domain.org
test@do-main.com
foo@bar.net
```

Comment: You don't need to escape a dot `.` inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `|` operator:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9.]+@[a-z]+[a-z-]+[a-z]+\.(com|net|org)$
```

Note that it also doesn't accept domains that starts\ends with a hyphen. If you do want to accept them:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9.]+@[a-z-]+\.(com|net|org)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex must allow only `com`, `net` or `org` after last `.` operator

Try below regex

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9\\.]+@[-a-z]\\.+(com|net|org)$
```